# How do I Figure out React Navigation Return Types?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm used to strongly typed languages, but still very new to TypeScript and I'm having difficulty with understanding the types of different methods and such from other libraries. But I'm using the react-navigation library and I'm trying to figure out the types of a few things related to the Stack screen navigation.

Here's some example code from the [official page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#api-definition):

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

If I dig into the `creatStackNavigator()` implementation, I see:

```
declare function StackNavigator({ initialRouteName, children, screenOptions, ...rest }: Props): JSX.Element;
```

So does this function return a `JSX.Element`? If so, why is it that when I try to use this type...:

```
const Stack: JSX.Element = createStackNavigator();
```

... that I get this error?:

```
Type 'TypedNavigator<Record<string, object | undefined>, StackNavigationState, StackNavigationOptions, StackNavigationEventMap, ({ initialRouteName, children, screenOptions, ...rest }: Props) => Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, keyts(2739)
```

I'm interested in the specifics of this case in React Navigation, as well as general tips to better figure out the return types of functions, components, etc.

**Edit**:
Specifically in my use case, I'm hoping to do something like the following, where I can have a function take the `StackNavigator` and use it to create screens so that I can have uniform options for all of my screens:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import StackNavigator, TypedNavigator, {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const DummyView = () => {
    return <View/>;
}

// Instead of "any", what can I use as the type for stackNav?
// Neither StackNavigator or TypedNavigator seemed to work, at least not with the imports I have for them.
function createStackScreen (stackNav : any , name:string, component: React.ComponentType<any>) {
    // I also think I'll have problems with the Screen
    return (<stackNav.Screen
        name={name}
        component={component}
        options={{
        headerShown: false
    }}/>);
}

const MyStack = createStackNavigator();

const Index = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MyStack.Navigator>
                {createStackScreen(MyStack, 'Main Screen', DummyView)}
                {createStackScreen(MyStack, 'Secondary Screen', DummyView)}
                {createStackScreen(MyStack, 'Tertiary Screen', DummyView)}
            </MyStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 1):

A react `FunctionComponent` is a function which takes a single argument which is a props object and returns a `JSX.Element`.  The `JSX.Element` is the DOM representation of the component, which is usually an element like `div`, but it can also be a `string`, `number`, or `null`.

```
declare function StackNavigator({ initialRouteName, children, screenOptions, ...rest }: Props): JSX.Element;
```

This definition means that `StackNavigator` is a function component taking props which include the properties `initialRouteName`, etc.

Importantly, **this is the definition of `StackNavigator`, not of `createStackNavigator`.**

`createStackNavigator` is a function which returns a `StackNavigator` function component ( a higher-order function).

```
declare const _default: <ParamList extends Record<string, object | undefined>>()
 => TypedNavigator<ParamList, StackNavigationState, StackNavigationOptions, StackNavigationEventMap, typeof StackNavigator>;
```

So the type of `Stack` would be `StackNavigator` rather than `JSX.Element` (specifically it is a `TypedNavigator` with lots of generic parameters).  It is a function which creates an element.

It is unnecessary to manually define any type for `Stack` since the type is already known to typescript based on the return type of `createStackNavigator`.

Comment: This kind of makes sense, thanks for the answer. I've tried typing `Stack` as a `StackNavigator` and a `TypedNavigator` and neither seemed to quite work.

And I definitely don't need it in the code snippet I provided above. Sorry, I should've been a little more specific about my use case. But my use case is a little more complicated than the one above. I'll edit my answer to try and detail my use case.

Comment: All of they generics are going to make it tough, so just use `typeof MyStack` and call it day.  But in my opinion passing in the StackNavigator object as an argument is unnecessary if there is only one. Just access the `MyStack` constant in the body of the `createStackScreen` function.